# Props variable is not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-props

I'm learning `react native` using `expo-cli`. I'm working on a little exercise to display information about movies after fetching them from API using `axios http client`. But when I try to pass data from a parent component `MoviesList` to a child component `MovieDetails` I get the following screen:

[image: My screen]

Here is my App component code :

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import MoviesList from './src/components/MoviesList';
import axios from 'axios';

    const API_KEY = "mykey";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          movies:[],
          movieToSearch:"avengers"
         };
      }

      componentDidMount=async()=>{
          const res = await axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${this.state.movieToSearch}&apikey=${API_KEY}`);
          // const data=await res.json();
          this.setState({ movies:res.data.Search });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={ { flex:1 } }>
            <Header title={"Films"} />
            <MoviesList movies={ this.state.movies } />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Code for MoviesList.js:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import MovieDetails from './MovieDetails';

class MoviesList extends Component{
    renderMovies(){
        const { movies } = this.props;
        if(movies){
            return movies.map(movie => {
                return <MovieDetails key={ movie.imdbID } movie = { movie } />
            });
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderMovies() }
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default MoviesList;
```

Code for MovieDetails.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from './CardSection';
import Button from './Button';

const MovieDetails = () =>{
    const { Title, Year, Poster } = props.movie;
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <Text>{ Title }</Text>
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
                <Text>{ Title }</Text>
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
                <Button btnLabel="Voir les details" />
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default MovieDetails;
```

Everything seems good in my code, and I don't know where the error is coming from.

Here is the github repo so that you can test it locally :https://github.com/jochri3/movieslist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert

```
   const { Title, Year, Poster } = props.movie;
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardSection>
                <Text>{ Title }</Text>
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
                <Text>{ Title }</Text>
            </CardSection>

            <CardSection>
                <Button btnLabel="Voir les details" />
            </CardSection>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

to

```
const MovieDetails = ({movie}) => ({
     <Card>
        <CardSection>
           <Text>{ movie.Title }</Text>
        </CardSection>
        ...      
     </Card>   
    })
```

and

```
class MoviesList extends Component{
    renderMovies(){
        const { movies } = this.props;
        if(movies){
            return movies.map(movie => {
                return <MovieDetails key={ movie.imdbID } movie = { movie } />
            });
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderMovies() }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

with

```
class MoviesList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
     }
    renderMovies = () => {
        const { movies } = this.props;

            return movies.map(movie => {
                return <MovieDetails key={ movie.imdbID } movie = { movie } />
            });

    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderMovies() }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried,but not still working,alway the same error

Comment: adding `constructor(props){
       super(props)
     }` has not solved the problem

Comment: I've edited my post by adding the `git repo` of the project to test locally

Comment: You are missing constructor(props)  in github

Comment: That is how the code was before i try your solutions.I've already tried and remove the constructor because it has not worked

Comment: So it was missing in the Card and CardSection

Comment: `const CardSection=(props)=>{
    const { children } = props;
    return (
        <View>
            { children }
        </View>
    )
};` and `const Card=(props)=>{
    const { children } = props;
    return (
        <View>
            { children }
        </View>
    )
};` but i still have the same error

Comment: @ChristianLisangola Did you remove constructor(props){ super(props) } in MoviesList now try adding it

Comment: could you push the latest changes once more in github

Comment: https://github.com/jochri3/movieslist/blob/master/src/components/MoviesList.js#L6

Answer (score 1):

Functional components pass `props` as an argument.

```
const MovieDetails = () =>{
    const { Title, Year, Poster } = props.movie;
    return (
        <Card>
...
```

To this:

```
const MovieDetails = (props) =>{
    const { Title, Year, Poster } = props.movie;
    return (
        <Card>
...
```

Comment: I've edited my post by adding the `git repo` of the project to test locally

Comment: @ChristianLisangola https://github.com/jochri3/movieslist/blob/master/src/components/MoviesList.js#L6

Comment: @ChristianLisangola https://github.com/jochri3/movieslist/blob/master/src/components/Card.js#L5

Comment: @David Tryon I've added `props` everywhere it was missing,but still the same problem

Comment: @ChristianLisangola Does it still say the problem occurs in `MovieDetails` component?  Has the error message changed?

Comment: Yes,i has not changed

Comment: Are you sure that your looking at the latest built code? Line 8 in `MovieDetails` definitely has props now.

Comment: Let me push again to github then you'll see

Comment: you still have a problem here: https://github.com/jochri3/movieslist/blob/master/src/components/MoviesList.js#L7

Comment: This is the updated code : github.com/jochri3/movieslist but doesn't work

Comment: Shoud i remove `constructor(){
        super(props);
    }` ?

Comment: Yes, or add props to the constuctor args:  `constructor(props){ super(props); }`

Comment: Thank you very much @Davin Tryon

Answer (score 1):

You are using functional component for MovieDetails as follow:

`const MovieDetails = () => { 
const { Title, Year, Poster } = props.movie; 
.......
}`

But actual implementation for it is as follow:

`const MovieDetails = (props) => { 
const { Title, Year, Poster } = props.movie; 
......
}`

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you very much,i've tried but i always have the same error

Comment: I've edited my post by adding the `git repo` of the project to test locally

Comment: you have the same mistakes in Card & CardSection. Add

Comment: `const CardSection=(props)=>{ const { children } = props; return ( <View> { children } </View> ) };` and `const Card=(props)=>{ const { children } = props; return ( <View> { children } </View> ) };` but i still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
const MovieDetails = () =>{
```

has to be

```
const MovieDetails = props => {
```

The component is a function and `props` are its argument.